# Javascript - how to get all elements/layers at coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a script to emulate a mouse click. I've had moderate success where I was able to click a single element that's at the top however this did not emulate the mouse click well enough as it did not click all the layers. Here is one script to get all elements at x, y - can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
function getAllElementsAt(x, y) {
    var $elements = $("body *").map(function () {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var l = offset.left;
        var t = offset.top;
        var h = $(this).height();
        var w = $(this).width();

        var maxx = l + w;
        var maxy = t + h;

        if ((y <= maxy && y >= t) && (x <= maxx && x >= l)) {
            console.log($(this));
        }
    });
}
```